# continuous strictly increasing function has left hand limits?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits

Let $f$ be a continuous function on [a,b] which is strictly increasing, and let $x_0\in (a,b]$.  Is it true that the left hand limit $\lim_{x\to x_0^-} f(x)$ exists? If not, is there an counterexample?

Comment: Yes, that is a requirement for continuity

Comment: If the function is continuous in some interval $[a,b]$, by definition, $\lim_{x \to c} f(x) = f(c)$ for all $c \in [a,b]$. The existence of the limit means that $\lim_{x \to c^+} f(x) = \lim_{x \to c^-} f(x) $, that is, the left and right limits are equal (you can try proving this).

Comment: And even if you drop the continuity requirement of $f$, it is still true by $f$ increasing